# Block Mousewheel Event Change Input Type Number

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I'm struggling in block mouse wheel to change input type number.

We right now have 300+ input types number in a process. Lucky, all the components share the same father. I'm trying in the parent component block that but I'm not achieving the result because of the locker service.

This is my solution right now:

Renderer:

```
({
  afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        var afterRend = this.superAfterRender();
        helper.setWheelEventOnInputTypeNumber(component);
    return afterRend;
  }
});
```

Helper:

```
setWheelEventOnInputTypeNumber: function (component, event, helper) {
    setTimeout($A.getCallback(function () {
        var inputs = component.find("container").getElement().querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
        inputs.forEach(function addEventOnWheel(inputNumber) {
            inputNumber.addEventListener("mousewheel", function (event) {
                event.target.blur();
            });
        });
    }), 0);
},
```

Component:

```
<span aura:id="container">
    {!v.body}
</span>
```

Is not working this solution. anyone know a way to do that?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you tried using event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: yes, we got this error if we try to use the preventDefault(): ```Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.``` Locker service blocks that.

Comment: Accordign to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251072/change-mouse-wheel-event-on-window-object-to-passive-false-javascript, the problem is not the locker service, but Google Chrome.

Comment: @FernandoGavinho thanks for sharing this. Just fyi, the preventDefault works good if we do the handler for each field.